# update file based on match from another file using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to ouput a new file based on a match.  In the `input` file there are a list of ids that will match `$5` before the `|` in file. If the two ids match then the entire line from file is part of the new file. If no match is found then it skips it and moves on. The `awk` below does run but the resulting `new` file is empty.  Thank you :).

**input**

```
DACH1
POLE2
GNG7
```

**file**

```
chr13   60737711    60737910    chr13:60737711-60737910 DIAPH3-673|gc=69.3
chr13   72337884    72338003    chr13:72337884-72338003 DACH1-674|gc=30.3
chr19   2591538 2591657 chr19:2591538-2591657   GNG7-183|gc=48.7
```

**desired output**

```
chr13   72337884    72338003    chr13:72337884-72338003 DACH1-674|gc=30.3
chr19   2591538 2591657 chr19:2591538-2591657   GNG7-183|gc=48.7
```

**awk**

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{a[$1]=$5;next} $5 in a{$5=a[$1];print $0}' input file > new
```

Comment: What do you think setting `FS="|"` is doing? Now count the number of `|`-separated fields in your input file. What is the value of the 5th field (`$5`) on each line? Now do you see the problem?

Comment: Thank you @Ed Morton I see the problem with my `awk` and your `awk` is very helpful :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use grep instead.

```
  grep -w -f inputfile filetomodify > newfile
```

From what I can see you just want to output the lines in the file that have a match entry in the input file. that is the world of grep :) the -f tells it to use a file as input patterns, each line in the input file is a pattern.

NOTE: use the -w option (whole word match) if you get matches that include something like GNG77-123 (because it starts with GNG7) or AGNG7-123 (because it has GNG7 in it)..

Comment: works great, not all that familiar with `grep` but it seems very useful.  Thank you for the explanation and for your help :)

Comment: @Chris it's usually a bad idea to just accept the first answer posted or to accept any answer at all without giving it a few hours after asking your question to see a selection of answers all with their pros/cons. A script that produces the expected output given some specific input is the starting point to identifying a solution, not the end point. This particular answer will quietly produce interesting errors given various contents of your files so YMMV when you start to use it on your real data. You were on the right track with awk.

Comment: @Chris, glad I could introduce you to grep, I recommend you look at other options for grep. and make the patterns in the input file more specific so that you do not get the problem of matching a line with AGNG74-183 for example because you have GNG7 in your input file just watch for it and let us know if you have any issues :).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} {k=$NF; sub(/-.*/,"",k)} k in a' input file
chr13   72337884    72338003    chr13:72337884-72338003 DACH1-674|gc=30.3
chr19   2591538 2591657 chr19:2591538-2591657   GNG7-183|gc=48.7
```

Comment: Thank you both for your help :)